# Phase plane interpretations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm really quite confused about what *phase planes/portraits* represent. I'm only considering homogeneous systems.

Suppose we have the system,

$$ \begin{bmatrix}x_1'  \\x_2'  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\3 & 2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1  \\x_2  \end{bmatrix}$$

The associated phase portrait is then,

[image]

I understand that to get the picture above, we had to take a number of points, multiply them by the coefficient matrix and plot the resulting points in the $x_1 - x_2$ plane. From what I've been told, the resulting phase plane is a graphical representation of $\frac{dx_1 }{dx_2 }$. That is what really confuses me. Why is that of any interest at all? How is that meant to give us the 'trajectories' of our solution when it doesn't contain '$t$' (assuming $x_1$ and $x_2$ are functions of $t$)

Answer (score 0):

It's an interpretation of the solutions of the equation as representing parametrisations of curves in a plane with a coordinate system $(x_1,x_2)$. Something like knowing the possible trajectories/orbits of a planet are elliptical, but not knowing on what ellipse (which requires an initial condition), and where at what time the planet is on a certain ellipse (which requires to know the $t$ value associated with the points $(x_1,x_2)$.

The reason one might be interested in these phase portraits, is that you can at a glance see features of your solutions. For instance, by inspecting your picture, I can see that the point $(0,0)$ is repulsive for your trajectories. A solution will never go through it. Solutions tend to start from a point far away from $(0,0)$, come close to it and then bounce away. Also, you can divide the plane in 4 regions. With an initial condition in one of those regions, you can never reach a different region.

[Take a look at these notes](http://www.math.psu.edu/tseng/class/Math251/Notes-PhasePlane.pdf) to see the kind of things you can read off of a phase portrait.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean by "as representing parametrisations of curves in a plane with a coordinate system $(x_1,x_2)"$

Comment: That's why I give an example. In other words, it's an answer to the question:"What is the shape of the trajectories/orbits represented by the solutions of the equations?".

Comment: So you mean that the actual solution(s) follows a similar path to the 'trajectories', that is, they could be paths which are scaled by some factor?

Comment: In your case, yes. If you scale a solution by a certain factor, it is still a solution of the equations. But it need not be the case in more general situations. Such phase portraits may be drawn for differential equations that don't have this scaling property.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw the actual solution curves $x_1=x_1(t)$, $x_2=x_2(t)$ in a three-dimensional coordinate system $(t,x_1,x_2)$. The phase portrait is what you get if you project this picture onto the $(x_1,x_2)$ plane.